# Xslt: populate innertext value of <a href="" /> in xslt during runtime

Tags: xslt

I tried a lot to see if any suggestion/answer would satisfy my requirement but could not find any.

I have an Xml file which I am using to get an output Html file using XslTransform API and an Xslt stylesheet.

My xml file has a rootnode which will have two attributes - **HyperlinkDisplayText** and **HyperlinkValue**.  This xml file is generated at runtime. So, the values of these attributes are not known at compile time.

My requirement is that the html output should display a hyperlink whose display text needs to be taken from the value of '**HyperlinkDisplayText**' and the hyperlink value needs to be taken from the value of "**HyperlinkValue**'.

For example,

```
<RootNode HyperlinkDisplayText="Google" HyperlinkValue="https://www.google.com/" />
```

This needs to be appears as [Google](https://www.google.com/).

For this, I tried several things in my xslt.  Below is a snapshot what I am trying in my xslt file -

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="@HyperlinkDisplayText and @HyperlinkValue">
    <h4 style="font-family: arial" align='center'>
      <a href="{./@HyperlinkValue}">@HyperlinkDisplayText</a>
    </h4>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

It is not working.  Any help is highly appreciated.

Regards,
kvk938

Answer (score 2):

Change `<a href="{./@HyperlinkValue}">@HyperlinkDisplayText</a>` to `<a href="{@HyperlinkValue}"><xsl:value-of select="@HyperlinkDisplayText"/></a>`. That assumes the context node is a `RootNode` element.